# VB.net adding values to 2 dimensional datetime array

Tags: vb.net

I defined a two dimensional array like that

```
Dim dates As DateTime(,) = {}
```

How can I put two dates into it?
Thank you.

Comment: You can't. That array has zero elements. An array would have to have elements for you to be able to set any of them. You need to spend some time learning how arrays work.

Comment: suppose the declaration would have been like that: e.g. Dim dates As DateTime(5,5) = {}. How can I put two dates into it? Thanks.

Comment: The same as you would for any other array. If you don't know how to do it for any other array, learn. It's not for us to teach you the basics. How arrays works is the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. People can be unhelpful and unfriendly on here, forgetting that they were inexperienced programmers at one time too. Take the time to read up here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/how-to-initialize-an-array-variable

```
Dim Dates(,) As Date = {
    {New Date(2000, 1, 1), New Date(2001, 1, 1)},
    {New Date(2000, 1, 2), New Date(2002, 1, 1)}
}
```